# How do I go to a specific character on the mac command line

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

I copy paste a command on the command line:

$hostname > This is a very llong command

and I realize that long is spelled wrong and I want to to llong to correct it. In VI I could just do /llo and it will take to that spot. Is there a way I can do this with mac bash terminal also.

Comment: [bash - How do I edit current shell command in VI - Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88515/how-do-i-edit-current-shell-command-in-vi)

Comment: First, I _know_ this isn't answering the op's question specifically about bash.  But, I'm a "tcsh" user (after starting on csh), way before there was a bash (and plain old sh just wasn't a good interactive shell).  In (t)csh, you can repeat the previous line with an edit like `^llo^lo`.  You don't need to up-arrow, just start the next command with the caret, after you enter your find/replace patterns and press enter, it just does the replacement and runs it!